# Run For-Loop multiple times in R and save results in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, repeat

I am still relatively new in dealing with R and in the forum, so please forgive me one or two mistakes. What I want to do is the following: I want to generate 6000 observations for 14 variables each.

This is what I've done so far. I have initialized the vectors for each variable with the appropriate length:

```
#Market1
price_1                           <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6002)
demandChartist_1                  <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6000)
demandFundamentalist_1            <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
percentFT_Wf_1                    <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
percentCT_Wc_1                    <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1       <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)

#Market2
price_2                           <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6002)
demandChartist_2                  <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6000)
demandFundamentalist_2            <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
percentFT_Wf_2                    <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
percentCT_Wc_2                    <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2       <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)

percentNoTrading                  <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 6001)
T <- 1:6000
```

The next step was to set the start values.

```
# set the first 4 values for price equal to 0, 1 whatever otherwise we can't compute the previous periods
price_1[1:4]  <- 0 
price_2[1:4]  <- 0 
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[1:3] <- 0
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[1:3] <- 0
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[1:3] <- 0
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[1:3] <- 0
a       <- 1
b       <- 0.05
c       <- 0.05
d       <- 0.975
e       <- 300
F1      <- 0
F2      <- 0
```

I have managed to set up the For loop so that all vectors are filled with the randomly generated values. (see code) Since these are randomly generated values, the accuracy of the model would increase significantly if I could execute the loop multiple times and create a dataframe for each variable, in which the 6000 observations from the first run are stored in column 1, the 6000 observations from the second run are stored in column 2 etc. and I could finally calculate an average value from each period.

```
for (i in 4:6002) {
  # [i-2] weil fitness tradingchartist der jetzigen Periode Demand der Periode t-2 also 2 erfordert.
  demandChartist_1[i-2]  =  
    b * (price_1[i-2] - price_1[i-3]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.05)
  # [i-2] weil fitness tradingFundamentalist der jetzigen Periode Demand der Periode t-2 also 2 erfordert.

  demandChartist_2[i-2]  =  
    b * (price_2[i-2] - price_2[i-3]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.05)

  demandFundamentalist_1[i-2] = 
    c * (F1 - price_1[i-2]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

  demandFundamentalist_2[i-2] = 
    c * (F2 - price_2[i-2]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

  fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i] = 
    (exp(price_1[i]) - exp(price_1[i-1])) * demandChartist_1[i-2] + 
    d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i-1]

  fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i] = 
    (exp(price_2[i]) - exp(price_2[i-1])) * demandChartist_2[i-2] + 
    d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i-1]

  fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i] = 
    (exp(price_1[i]) - exp(price_1[i-1])) * demandFundamentalist_1[i-2] + 
    d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i-1]  

  fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i] = 
    (exp(price_2[i]) - exp(price_2[i-1])) * demandFundamentalist_2[i-2] + 
    d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i-1]  

  percentCT_Wc_1[i] = 
    exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i]) / 
    (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i]) +
       exp(0)
    )

  percentCT_Wc_2[i] = 
    exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i]) / 
    (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i]) +
       exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i]) + 
       exp(0)
    )

  percentFT_Wf_1[i] = 
    exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i]) / 
    (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i]) +
       exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i]) + 
       exp(0)
    )

  percentFT_Wf_2[i] = 
    exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i]) / 
    (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i]) +
       exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i]) + 
       exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i]) + 
       exp(0)
    )

  percentNoTrading[i] = 
    1- percentCT_Wc_1[i] - percentFT_Wf_1[i] - percentCT_Wc_2[i] - percentFT_Wf_2[i]

  price_1[i] = 
    price_1[i-1] + 
    a * ((percentCT_Wc_1[i-1] * demandChartist_1[i-1] + 
        percentFT_Wf_1[i-1] * demandFundamentalist_1[i-1]
          )
        ) + 
    rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

  price_2[i] = 
    price_2[i-1] + 
    a * ((percentCT_Wc_2[i-1] * demandChartist_2[i-1] + 
        percentFT_Wf_2[i-1] * demandFundamentalist_2[i-1]
          )
        ) + 
    rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done? I would be very grateful for any help! 
Cheers

Comment: Can you water down your question to something less verbose?

Comment: I want to randomly generate 6000 observations for 14 variables each under the conditions seen in the for loop and save them in seperate dataframes. my question is how can i repeat the for-loop lets say 50 times so that i would generate 50 times 6000 observations for each variable and store the results in 50 seperate colums in a dataframe (for example the data_frame for the first variable would have 50 columns and 6000 rows) ?

Comment: So, you want 14 dataframe each with 50 columns and 6000 observations, am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not definitely not easy to track.

Here, the couple of points I will try to change in you want to get 14 dataframe with 50 columns and 6000 observations.

```r
# definition of dataframe
#Market1
price_1                           <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
demandChartist_1                  <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
demandFundamentalist_1            <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
percentFT_Wf_1                    <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
percentCT_Wc_1                    <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1 <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1       <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)

#Market2
price_2                           <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
demandChartist_2                  <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
demandFundamentalist_2            <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
percentFT_Wf_2                    <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
percentCT_Wc_2                    <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2 <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2       <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)

percentNoTrading                  <- matrix(ncol = 50, nrow =6002, 0L)
```

Then, your definition of the first value:

```r
#set the first 4 values for price equal to 0, 1 whatever otherwise we cant compute the previous periods
price_1[1:4,]  <- 0 
price_2[1:4,]  <- 0 
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[1:3,] <- 0
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[1:3,] <- 0
fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[1:3,] <- 0
fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[1:3,] <- 0
a       <- 1
b       <- 0.05
c       <- 0.05
d       <- 0.975
e       <- 300
F1      <- 0
F2      <- 0
```

And finally, your big chunk of code including a second loop for columns

```r
for(j in 1:50)
{
  for (i in 4:6002) {
    # [i-2] weil fitness tradingchartist der jetzigen Periode Demand der Periode t-2 also 2 erfordert.
    demandChartist_1[i-2,j]  =  
      b * (price_1[i-2,j] - price_1[i-3,j]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.05)
    # [i-2] weil fitness tradingFundamentalist der jetzigen Periode Demand der Periode t-2 also 2 erfordert.

    demandChartist_2[i-2,j]  =      b * (price_2[i-2,j] - price_2[i-3,j]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.05)
    print("1 OK")
    demandFundamentalist_1[i-2,j] =     c * (F1 - price_1[i-2,j]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

    demandFundamentalist_2[i-2,j] =     c * (F2 - price_2[i-2,j]) + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

    fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j] =     (exp(price_1[i,j]) - exp(price_1[i-1,j])) * demandChartist_1[i-2,j] + 
      d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i-1,j]

    fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j] =     (exp(price_2[i,j]) - exp(price_2[i-1,j])) * demandChartist_2[i-2,j] + 
      d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i-1,j]

    fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j] =     (exp(price_1[i,j]) - exp(price_1[i-1,j])) * demandFundamentalist_1[i-2,j] + 
      d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i-1,j]  

    fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j] =     (exp(price_2[i,j]) - exp(price_2[i-1,j])) * demandFundamentalist_2[i-2,j] + 
      d * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i-1,j]  

    percentCT_Wc_1[i,j] =     exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j]) / 
      (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j]) +
         exp(0)
      )

    percentCT_Wc_2[i,j] = 
      exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j]) / 
      (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j]) +
         exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(0)
      )

    percentFT_Wf_1[i,j] = 
      exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j]) / 
      (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j]) +
         exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(0)
      )

    percentFT_Wf_2[i,j] = 
      exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j]) / 
      (exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_1[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_1[i,j]) +
         exp(e * fitnessTradingChartist_Ac_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(e * fitnessTradingFundamentalist_Af_2[i,j]) + 
         exp(0)
      )

    percentNoTrading[i,j] = 
      1- percentCT_Wc_1[i,j] - percentFT_Wf_1[i,j] - percentCT_Wc_2[i,j] - percentFT_Wf_2[i,j]

    price_1[i,j] = 
      price_1[i-1,j] + 
      a * ((percentCT_Wc_1[i-1,j] * demandChartist_1[i-1,j] + 
              percentFT_Wf_1[i-1,j] * demandFundamentalist_1[i-1,j]
      )
      ) + 
      rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)

    price_2[i,j] = 
      price_2[i-1,j] + 
      a * ((percentCT_Wc_2[i-1,j] * demandChartist_2[i-1,j] + 
              percentFT_Wf_2[i-1,j] * demandFundamentalist_2[i-1,j]
      )
      ) + 
      rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=0.01)
  }
}
```

Hope it is what you are looking for. There is maybe easier way to do but the structure of your code needs a bit of optimization first.